# How to debug "run time 1" error in Java?

Tags: java, client, chat, server

I am new to Java and I would like to run this code but every time it says error run time 1!

Also, would someone advise me to use specific program to run Java code?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatServer
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ServerSocket    server   = null;
   private DataInputStream streamIn =  null;

   public ChatServer(int port)
   {  try
     {  System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
        server = new ServerSocket(port);  
        System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
        System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 
        socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
        open();
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done)
        {  try
           {  String line = streamIn.readUTF();
              System.out.println(line);
              done = line.equals(".bye");
           }
           catch(IOException ioe)
           {  done = true;
           }
        }
        close();
      }
     catch(IOException ioe)
     {  System.out.println(ioe); 
     }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {  streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  ChatServer server = null;
      if (args.length != 1)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatServer port");
      else
         server = new ChatServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
   }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace for the error, and be more specific about what you don't understand

Comment: Can be closed as lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a `DataInputStream` when you just want to read lines of text? Try a `BufferedReader` instead.

Comment: Doesn't address the issue, whatever it is.